# Обеспечить безопасность сервера

Tags: php, безопасность, websocket

Как обезопасить сервер, на который приходят данные, то есть, чтобы на сервер приходили только данные с моего сайта.
Можно ли положить сервер, зная его адрес?
Пытаюсь сделать для сокет сервера проверку на HTTP_REFERER, но там пустое значение

Comment: Я бы в таком случае сначала отправлял `POST`-запрос на сервер, сервер проверит этот запрос на `referer` (можно кстати и какой-то токен прикрутить сессийный), сервер отдаст клиенту ключ для соединения по сокету. Кстати, этот ключ можно привязать к IP и юзерагенту. А потом передавать этот ключ при соединении с сокетом.

Comment: А злоумышленник способен как-то подменять referer?
Идея с ключом хорошая, наверно ее и придется реализовать

Comment: `referer` нельзя подменить со стороны браузера, то есть если я со своего сайта хочу втайне от пользователя послать к вам вебсокет - он не пройдет. Но если злоумышленник будет посылать запрос со своего пк с помощью сторонего софта - то он может подменить всё что ему захочется.

Comment: В таком случае поможет добавление секретного ключа, который может генерироватся на стороне клиента по секретному алгоритму. К примеру, таймстамп + солёний хеш от строки таймстампа. Но код обфусцировать, чтоб это было сложно разобрать. Таким образом будет намного сложнее отправить запрос, хотя и не невозможно. Главное чтоб сложность была такой, чтоб потенциальному злоумышленику было невыгодно проводить атаку.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую попробовать что-то с ajax (на клиенте за сокет отвечает js)

Comment: Синхронно ответили)
Для обфускации подойдет обычный онлайн сервис obfuscator io?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110362/discussion-between-k1s3l-and--).

Comment: Да, как раз думал советовать его. Так же у него есть CLI, то есть можно локально автоматически обфусцировать, что очень удобно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, допустим у вас сейчас такой код:

```
const socketEndpoint = "wss://example.com/socket";
const socketConnection = new WebSocket(socketEndpoint);
```

Для начала, я бы отправлял `POST`-запрос на сервер, чтоб он проверил этот запрос на referer и сессийные куки и отдал клиенту токен для соединения по сокету.
Кстати, этот ключ можно привязать к IP и юзерагенту.
Так же, как вариант, для затруднения обхода защиты, сервер в случае проблем может возвращать случайный неработающий токен вместо сообщения об ошибке.

Но `referer` можно подменить, если отправлять запрос не из браузера, а из стороннего софта. Поэтому нужно затруднить отправление запросов не из своего хоста, например, добавить секретную подпись на стороне клиента, которая генерируется по непонятному алгоритму, а потом обфусцировать этот код. Для обфускатора могу посоветовать [obfuscator.io](https://obfuscator.io/) и выкрутить все параметры на максимум =)

```
// 1. Отправляем запрос на токен к серверу. Он проверяет куки и `referer` и возвращает токен.
const securityEndpoint = "/getSocketToken.php";
const response = await fetch(securityEndpoint).then(response => response.json());
const socketToken = response.socketToken;

// 2. Создаем "подпись" - таймстамп + соленый хеш
// ! Сервер должен проверять и таймстамп, и его подпись, и сам токен
const signatureSecret = "someSecretString" + window.location.hostname;
const timestamp = Date.now();
const signature = timestamp + ":" + md5(timestamp + socketToken + signatureSecret).substr(0, 8);

// 3. Передаем эти данные серверу
const params = "?token=" + socketToken + "&signature=" + signature;
const socketEndpoint = "wss://example.com/socket" + params;
const socketConnection = new WebSocket(socketEndpoint);
```

Так же советую разбросать генерацию этих кодов на пару функций для усложнения анализа.

Comment: Обфусцированный код всегда можно деобфусцировать

Comment: @andreymal, верно, это лишь вопрос времени. Так же есть два вида обфускаторов. Первые просто берут код как строку, шифрую ее, а потом расшифровывают и исполняют через `eval`. В таком случае достаточно заменить `eval` на `console.log` и получить код. `obfuscator.io` работает иначе. Он парсит код как синтаксическую конструкцию и вносит разные манипуляции. Поэтому, если выкрутить настройки на максимум - деобфусцировать такой код ооочень сложно и за него возьмутся только если оно того стоит. Но никто не мешает переобфусцировать код раз в неделю и изменять ключ - и начинай сначала=)

Comment: В крайнем случае из кода можно просто вытащить функцию, генерирующую что нужно, и просто использовать её как есть, даже не пытаясь деобфусцировать. Специфика javascript такова, что даже с выкруткой на максимум это не запредельно сложно